# How to handle signals when a Qt object isn't created through Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Hi I've got a spare moment so decided to look at Qt and how easily I can port my windows applications to Qt.

My only real problem is a couple of controls that will need re-implementing under Qt. I've already handled the basic drawing of the control but my control creates a child scroll bar.  The problem is that this scrollbar is created dynamically as part of my new Widget (i.e. `m_Scrollbar` is a member of the widget). How can I then respond to movement of the scrollbar.  Under other circumstances this is easy as I'd just create an `on_myscrollbar_sliderMoved` function under my `protected slots` and handle it there. This does however rely on the `QScrollBar` being called `myscrollbar`.  As I've created the object dynamically (i.e. not through designer) how do I capture this signal?

I'm guessing this is really simple and I'm missing the obvious :)

Comment: I think you need to spend more time in Qt docs.

Comment: Probably true ... but given I picked up Qt for the first time about an hour ago I reckon I'm not doing "too" badly :D  I like it though ... its pretty easy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
connect( myScrollbar, SIGNAL( <signal signature>), this, SLOT( <slot signature>));
```

Call connect after creating the scroll bar (I presume that you need this signal handling immediately after creating the scroll bar).

I assumed myScrollbar is of type QScrollBar* and that the slot is defined as a member in your class.

When myScrollbar is destroyed, the connection is removed (disconnect is called).

See the documentation of QObject::connect and QObject::disconnect methods.

**Later edit** - to be more concrete, in your code it could be:

```
myScrollbar = new QScrollBar; // Create the scroll bar
// ... add it to the layout, etc.
// ... and connect the signal to your slot
connect( myScrollbar, SIGNAL( sliderMoved( int)), this, SLOT( handleSliderMoved( int)));
```

where handleSliderMoved is the slot method of your class.

Comment: Sweet ... I knew it would be something simple!  Cheers :)